# move_uploaded_file() changes name of chinese file joomla

Tags: php, joomla

While uploading a file with pure **chinese** font `move_uploaded_file()` function changes the name into some symbol while storing into image folder. I am using joomla website.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

local files must be saved using the system encoding: in short if your system uses a chinese encoding, you have to convert the filename to that encoding

if your php files are utf-8, and you are using windows, you must use, for example

```
$destfilename = iconv("UTF-8", "GBK", "您好.txt");

move_uploaded_file($temp, $destfilename);
```

and you must use the same treatment with function such mkdir, rename, etc

Comment: by using these code file is not uploaded even but simple move_uploaded_file($temp, $destfilename); function works only problem is it changes chinese font ie 1356281840湯.png  to 1356281840æ¹¯.jpg